# Terraform Azure Data Factory Identity

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to grant access to a keyvault for the newly created data factory. To achieve this I had following code ...

```
    module "subscription" {
      source = "../../general/subscription_getdetails"
    }
    
    module "df_resourcegroup" {
      source = "../../general/rg_getdetails"
      rg_name_solution = var.df_rg_name_solution
      rg_name_seqnr    = var.df_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    module "location" {
      source = "../../general/location/location_getdetails"
      location_name = var.df_location_name
      location_tier = var.df_location_tier
    }
    
    module "keyvault" {
      source = "../../security/kv_getdetails"
      kv_name_solution    = var.kv_name_solution
      kv_name_seqnr       = var.kv_name_seqnr
      kv_name_purpose     = var.kv_name_purpose
      kv_location_name    = var.kv_location_name
      kv_location_tier    = var.kv_location_tier
      kv_rg_name_solution = var.kv_rg_name_solution
      kv_rg_name_seqnr    = var.kv_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
      name                     = "adf-${module.df_resourcegroup.sitecode}-${module.subscription.environment}-${var.df_name_dataset}-${var.df_name_seqnr}"
      location                 = module.location.azure
      resource_group_name      = module.df_resourcegroup.rg.name
      public_network_enabled   = var.df_allow_public_access
  identity {
      type = "SystemAssigned"
  }    }
    
    
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "df_grant_keyvault_read" {
      key_vault_id = module.keyvault.kv.id
      tenant_id    = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity[0].tenant_id
      object_id    = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity[0].principal_id
    
      key_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    
      secret_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    }
```

But there must be something wrong with this as I'm getting this error... (I've tried not to address it as a list, doesn't work).

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on _modules/das/df_create/main.tf line 68, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "df_grant_keyvault_read":
│   68:   tenant_id    = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity[0].tenant_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_data_factory.df.identity is empty list of object
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: It States v0.15.4

Comment: The error message implies the resource generated no attributes for that object. Are you expecting the resource to have information for `identity`?

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying to use SelfSigned Identity I got:

`│ The argument "object_id" is required, but no definition was found.`

It is known issue and is already reported on [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15167) To overcome this we could use data source `azuread_service_principal`

```
    module "subscription" {
      source = "../../general/subscription_getdetails"
    }
    
    module "df_resourcegroup" {
      source = "../../general/rg_getdetails"
      rg_name_solution = var.df_rg_name_solution
      rg_name_seqnr    = var.df_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    module "location" {
      source = "../../general/location/location_getdetails"
      location_name = var.df_location_name
      location_tier = var.df_location_tier
    }
    
    module "keyvault" {
      source = "../../security/kv_getdetails"
      kv_name_solution    = var.kv_name_solution
      kv_name_seqnr       = var.kv_name_seqnr
      kv_name_purpose     = var.kv_name_purpose
      kv_location_name    = var.kv_location_name
      kv_location_tier    = var.kv_location_tier
      kv_rg_name_solution = var.kv_rg_name_solution
      kv_rg_name_seqnr    = var.kv_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
      name                     = "adf-${module.df_resourcegroup.sitecode}-${module.subscription.environment}-${var.df_name_dataset}-${var.df_name_seqnr}"
      location                 = module.location.azure
      resource_group_name      = module.df_resourcegroup.rg.name
      public_network_enabled   = var.df_allow_public_access
  identity {
      type = "SystemAssigned"
  }    }

data "azuread_service_principal" "data_factory_managed_identity" {
  object_id = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity.0.principal_id
}
    
    
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "df_grant_keyvault_read" {
      key_vault_id = module.keyvault.kv.id
      tenant_id    = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity[0].tenant_id
      object_id    = data.azuread_service_principal.data_factory_managed_identity.object_id
    
      key_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    
      secret_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way but with UserAssigned Identity....

```
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "uai_adf" {
  resource_group_name = module.df_resourcegroup.rg.name
  location            = module.location.azure

  name = "id-${module.df_resourcegroup.sitecode}-${module.subscription.environment}-adf-0${var.df_name_dataset}"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
  name                     = "adf-${module.df_resourcegroup.sitecode}-${module.subscription.environment}-${var.df_name_dataset}-${var.df_name_seqnr}"

  location                 = module.location.azure
  resource_group_name      = module.df_resourcegroup.rg.name

  public_network_enabled   = var.df_allow_public_access
 
  identity {
      type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [ azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.id ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "df_grant_keyvault_read_secret" {
  key_vault_id = module.keyvault.kv.id
  tenant_id    = "${azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.tenant_id}"
  object_id    = "${azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.principal_id}"

  key_permissions = []
  secret_permissions = [ "Get" ]
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work for you? I tried it (also with a managed identity), but when I try to create a linked service that pulls its secret from Key Vault, I get an error that no managed identity has been set up (even though in the Azure portal I can clearly see that a managed identity has been set up).

Answer (score 1):

```
 module "subscription" {
      source = "../../general/subscription_getdetails"
    }
    
    module "df_resourcegroup" {
      source = "../../general/rg_getdetails"
      rg_name_solution = var.df_rg_name_solution
      rg_name_seqnr    = var.df_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    module "location" {
      source = "../../general/location/location_getdetails"
      location_name = var.df_location_name
      location_tier = var.df_location_tier
    }
    
    module "keyvault" {
      source = "../../security/kv_getdetails"
      kv_name_solution    = var.kv_name_solution
      kv_name_seqnr       = var.kv_name_seqnr
      kv_name_purpose     = var.kv_name_purpose
      kv_location_name    = var.kv_location_name
      kv_location_tier    = var.kv_location_tier
      kv_rg_name_solution = var.kv_rg_name_solution
      kv_rg_name_seqnr    = var.kv_rg_name_seqnr
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
      name                     = "adf-${module.df_resourcegroup.sitecode}-${module.subscription.environment}-${var.df_name_dataset}-${var.df_name_seqnr}"
      location                 = module.location.azure
      resource_group_name      = module.df_resourcegroup.rg.name
      public_network_enabled   = var.df_allow_public_access
  identity {
      type = "SystemAssigned"
  }    }
    
    **data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}**
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "df_grant_keyvault_read" {
      key_vault_id = module.keyvault.kv.id
      **tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id**
      object_id    = azurerm_data_factory.df.identity[0].principal_id
    
      key_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    
      secret_permissions = [
        "Get",
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Please try running the code along with the highlighted code.

Comment: I got this error `│ The argument "principal_id" is required, but no definition was found.
`  and this issue explains this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/29923